# using spring boot in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, web

I am starting a new project with maven and spring boot and got problems already at the very beginning :-) Finally it works now, but I would like to know what I did wrong:

I simply wanted to add spring boot to my project by adding the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-build</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

which can be found in Maven-Central. 
This doesn't work.

Then I found out, that the correct dependency is without "-build":

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I would like to understand, where is the problem:

Do I get the info on the wrong place and maven central is wrong ?
Or why did I get problems from beginning. What is the correct aproach ?

Comment: is there any tutorial you are following?

Comment: according to maven site :: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.5.9.RELEASE
it is without build... getting your dependencies always from maven site is recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the best approaches for creating new SpringBoot projects is to use the Spring Initilizr: https://start.spring.io/. With this tool you will get a generated .zip file which containts the basic maven/gradle folder structure and has the correct dependencies in your pom.xml or build.gradle file. During the creation of the .zip you can easily search for you required SpringBoot dependencies like `Web` or `Security` and with a tick in the checkbox will get you the right dependency.

You can also use a Plugin for Eclipse called Spring Tool Suite which enables you to create fresh SpringBoot project out of eclipse with rightclick -> New -> New Spring Starter Project. This is also available in IntelliJ or you use the dedicated IDEA STS from Eclipse https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

Comment: I try to understand what is the problem. I guess there are several ways to create a new springboot project. But I try to understand the problem in Maven Central. I tried to create dependencies using Maven Central and most of them simply can't be found. Is Maven-Central a dead Portal which should not be used anymore, or I am dooing something wrong ?